# Visual studio installation -How to replace an evaluation version installation with a copy that is licensed by the company

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, licensing

I installed VS 2015 pro trial. and the trial is over. I have a **iso** copy that is licensed by my company.

I uninstalled VS 2015 and installed again using the licensed ***iso***. but it did not work, vs 2015 is still not licensed.

I assume I should remove something and then reinstall, but I'm not sure what.

ps: I'm running windows 10.

Comment: Either sign into your company or Microsoft account that has the MSDN license linked or use a visual studio product key to activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To active the VS professional or enterprise version, we can directly enter the product key or sign into Visual Studio with a Microsoft account, or an organizational account, that is associated with an MSDN subscription or a Visual Studio Online subscription. For the detail information, you can check this: [How to: Upgrade from a Trial Edition of Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442061.aspx). If you are not sure about this, you can confirm it with your company.

If you want to uninstall the existing VS 2015, you can follow the steps as below:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio using the forcibly command like vs_professional.exe /uninstall /force or go to Control Panel—Programs and Features, right click the VS Professional 2015, Change-Uninstall.
2. Manually remove the related folders and registry keys as below:

•   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

•   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

•  C:\users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015

•  C:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

• C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

• C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0

Go to the registry editor (start >> run >> regedit) and remove/rename the following registries- (Please back up the registry table before the modification)

•   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

•   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

•   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

•   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config

3. Download and use the Visual Studio Uninstaller tool: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases to remove any remaining of VS 2015.